# Explode array in the group of 3 words and wrap it

Tags: php, explode

i am trying to group 3 words in a span from a string. For example i have a title

```
$string = "one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen";
```

**Resultant output:**

```
<span>one two three</span>
<span>four five six</span>
<span>seven eight nine</span>
<span>ten eleven twelve</span>
<span>thirteen fourteen fifteen</span>
<span>sixteen seventeen</span>
```

Here is the code

```
<?php
$title_my = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven 
twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen';
$word_count = str_word_count($title_my);
/****/
if($word_count < 5):
 $word_i = '12';
else:
 $word_i = '13';
endif;
/****/
$lines = explode("\n", wordwrap($title_my,$word_i, "\n"));
echo '<pre>';
 $i = 1;
 foreach ($lines as &$value) {
  echo '<span class="green'.$i.'">'.$value.' </span>';
 }
 echo '</pre>';
 ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hope this one will be helpful. Here we are using `explode`, `implode`, `array_map`and `array_chunk`

[**Try this code snippet here**](https://eval.in/852945)

```
<?php

$string="one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen";
$data=array_chunk(explode(" ", $string),3);//splitting words into group of 3
$data=array_map(function($value){
    return sprintf("<span>%s</span>",implode(" ",$value)) ; //adding span tags around it.
},$data);

echo implode("\n",$data);
```

**Output:**

```
<span>one two three</span>
<span>four five six</span>
<span>seven eight nine</span>
<span>ten eleven twelve</span>
<span>thirteen fourteen fifteen</span>
<span>sixteen seventeen</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use regex to do this work. Use regex in php [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php).

```
$html = preg_replace("/(\w+\s\w+(\s\w+\s)?)/", "<span>$1</span>\n", $title_my);
```

Check it in [demo](https://3v4l.org/anMAc)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use it

```
$title_my = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen';
$lines = explode(" ", $title_my);
$group=3;
$k=1;
echo '<pre>';
for ($i = 0; $i < count($lines); $i = $i + $group) {
    echo '<span class="green' . $k . '">';
    for ($j = $i; $j < $i + $group; $j++) {
        if (isset($lines[$j])) {
            echo $lines[$j]." ";
        }
    }
    echo ' </span></br>';
    $k++;
}
echo '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't get any simpler / more efficient than this:

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/5ZATt))

```
$title_my = 'one two three four five six seven eight nine ten eleven twelve thirteen fourteen fifteen sixteen seventeen';
echo '<span>' , preg_replace('~\S+\s\S+\s\S+\K\s~', "</span><span>", $title_my) , '</span>';
```

Output:

```
<span>one two three</span>
<span>four five six</span>
<span>seven eight nine</span>
<span>ten eleven twelve</span>
<span>thirteen fourteen fifteen</span>
<span>sixteen seventeen</span>
```

The pattern matches the space after every third word.  This space is replaced by a `</span>` and an `<span>`.  The entire string is prepended with `<span>` and appended with `</span>` to ensure all tags are balanced.

I could have used: `~\S(?:\s\S+){2}\K\s~` but capture groups cause drag on performance.

The `\K` means restart the fullstring match -- in other words: "forget all matched characters up to this point".